# How do you manage your PHP and SQL file once uploaded to a server?

Tags: php, server, xampp, backend

First of all I apologize for the dumb question. I'm new with all this. I already searched an answer on Google, but I couldn't find anything comprehensible for me. 
So, I managed to create my html, CSS, JavaScript files. I managed to install XAMPP, create SQL databases, access and update them with PHP from my html page.
Now I have full access to my files, since they're on my computer. But how does it work when I move them to a server?
First, what files should I move exactly? All the XAMPP folder? Just html, css, js and PHP?
Second, once uploaded the files, how can I access them, for updating, or for viewing the database? Can I still use XAMPP or after uploading the files to a server XAMPP becomes useless?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: It sounds like your question is mostly about how to get started with XAMPP, and little to do with sql server. I suggest removing the sql-server tag and adding the xampp tag.

Comment: The server will have something like XAMPP on it (XAMPP is server software). Sometimes your code needs tweaking after you move it from your local machine to a server because the cofiguration on the server may be different to your local machine eg user name and password for MySQL may be different etc .....

Comment: Choosing the right server for you is important. I pay about £12 (UK) / month and have almost complete control of an Apache server running as virtual hosting. As well as using FileZilla I can also SSH (I just need the root password for the server which they give you) into the server to change configuration. I have not had to do much configuration but did have to get my head round SSL certificates and also changing ownership of directories used for uploading files from websites using HTTP as opposed to uploading files with SFTP like FileZilla.

Comment: Any follow-ups to the answers provided?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to upload file to a online server. there are many tools which can allow you upload them. In my Case i use [filezila](https://filezilla-project.org/).
This is how it is presented:
[image: file zila presentation]

you will move everything located under xamp/htdocs/YOUR_PROJECT and move it on the server ( in my case under public_html folder). Html, php, css, ...

You can delete, rename or modify them within filezila at server file section as described in the picture. Right click on a file > all actions will be seen

for viewing the database check in Admin panet of your host website in my case [hostinger](https://hpanel.hostinger.com/) and on Databases choose for example phpmyadmin and you will be redirected to you Database panel to view all your databases

I think this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider presumably already has the equivalent of your XAMPP stack installed. (Unless you're starting with an unmanaged VPserver, in which case you'll have to install and configure an Apache-MySQL-PHP stack before your website will function.) Assuming a standard hosting solution, you will only need to upload the files specific to your project.

Basic steps to deploy from local to remote server:

1. Using an FTP client of your choice, upload your PHP, HTML, CSS, JS, image etc. files to your server's `public_html` folder. (Full path will be something like `/home/example.com/public_html/` on a Linux server, depending on your hosting provider.)
2. Use a database manager (such as PHPMyAdmin) to upload the SQL file into a database you've created.
3. Update any absolute paths you may have used in your PHP files, reflecting the live/production server's filesystem structure.
4. Update your database-connecting PHP file(s) with the appropriate credentials.  (They're probably different from your local server's user/password.)
5. You will want to ensure that your remote server's configuration supports all the functionality your code depends on (e.g. PHP modules and other configuration).

If you put a bit of thought into your code, you won't have to maintain separate local/remote files, and won't have to bother with steps 3 & 4. You can e.g. define your configuration based on a local IP address check (we're testing for both IPv4/6), as follows:

```
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1'])) {
    // local config here
} else { 
    // remote config here
}
```

Then, does your local server become useless? If you don't ever intend to develop code again -- yes. Otherwise, you will probably want to develop and test your code on your local machine, and only deploy it to your live/production server when you're satisfied it's stable enough for public release. You **don't** want to do your R&D on the live server!